# Custom initializer for get_variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

How can one specify a custom initializer as the third argument for `tf.get_variable()`? Specifically, I have a variable `y` which I want to initialize using another (already initialized) variable `x`.

This is easy to do using `tf.Variable()`, just say, `y = tf.Variable(x.initialized_value())`. But I couldn't find an analog in the documentation for `tf.get_variable()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `x.initialized_value()` as well. For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(1.0)
y = tf.get_variable('y', initializer=x.initialized_value())

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    print(sess.run(y)) # prints 1.0
```